# We are trying to build SSIS solution using CI pipeline in Azure and it is failing because our solution in password protected

Tags: azure-devops, ssis

Is there any way we can pass the password for the solution to get built properly with no error?

Comment: If your project/packages do not contain any sensitive data you could remove password protection from your project and packages to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Filburt - We have packages with crucial DB information thus we cant remove the password. Any other way out?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) DevOps Tools Azure DevOps extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver15), there's an option to specify the password for your project.

> ##### Project password
>
> Password of the SSIS project and its packages. This argument is only valid when the protection level of the SSIS project and packages is EncryptSensitiveWithPassword or EncryptAllWithPassword. For package deployment model, all packages must share the same password specified by this argument.

Please make sure to use Version 1.* , since the project password is a Version 1.* property.

> Enhancements in version 1.*:
>
> - Remove the dependency on Visual Studio and SSIS designer. Build task can run on Microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent with Windows OS and .NET framework 4.6.2 or higher.
> - No need of installing out-of-box components.
> - **Support protection level EncryptionWithPassword and EncryptionAllWithPassword**.

Comment: Thanks! So we did try to build using this tool and it was successful. While deploying we were using Copy Task, but the files got corrupted.
We switched to Deploy task of the same tool and we are facing an error. 
Despitet getting a .ispac file it is searching for SSISManifest file.